# Codeigniter loads a page very slow

Tags: mysql, apache, performance, codeigniter, xampp

I have a page in codeigniter which loads very slow.

Environment: works fast on localhost (XAMPP runs on this PC too).
This PC is connected to a router. The tester laptop is connected to this router's wifi interface.

Controller: Loads data from model
Model: Loads data from the mysql database
View: Displays pictures from the xampp's folder (all of the pictures size is 1,7 MB)

I use ActiveRecord for the querys.

Could you please help me where should I start the debugging process and how?

Answer (score 2):

I'd have a look at using the [profiler](http://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/profiling.html) which is built into CodeIgniter.

This will give you a view of what is happening 'under the hood' by putting a section with information at the bottom of each page which allows you to look at queries and execution times, memory usage, benchmarks and more.

Read over the documentation and you can customise it to display what you need. This way you'll hopefully be able to identify any bottlenecks that may be occurring in your application.

**Please note** that based on the environment you've described the load times could be slow due to a poor wireless signal, resolution issues, or something caused by an Apache / XAMPP setup which may be suboptimal.

The profiler will only help you identify if the problem is with your web application, although bear in mind that this may also be slow if there is something amiss with your setup. You could verify if this is the case by ensuring that another site or application accessed remotely from your XAMPP install works at a reasonable level of performance.

Comment: Thank you, the profiler worked well but the result was the same on the two computers while on the tester laptop the site load time was more than 2 minutes.

Answer (score 0):

Reduce the sizes of the images that are used in View and also optimize your code and contents please visit here for further details:
http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2014/04/optimize-php-code/